# Hiding the ticks on the x-axes clips the chart (Chart.JS)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to hide the ticks on the x-axis of a bubble chart.

I tried using "display: false" within the ticks property.

It does remove the ticks however the chart is now being clipped.

Is there a way I can hide these ticks without affecting the appearance of the chart or to maybe add some padding so the chart's appearance isn't affected?

[Appearance before the ticks are removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLnH0.png)

[Clipping once the ticks are removed with "display: false"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsHTd.png)

You can see the code for the chart I have created below:

```
xAxes : [
    {
        id : 'first-x-axis',
        ticks : {
            display : false,
            min :  <  ? php echo $min ?  > , // Controls where axis starts
            max :  <  ? php echo $max ?  > , // Controls where axis finishes
            stepSize :  <  ? php echo $step ?  > // Control the gap between the first x-axis value and the last x-axis value
        },
        gridLines : {
            display : false,
            lineWidth : 7 // Width of bottom line
        }
    }
]
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

You can adjust the height/length of the tick marks by using "tickMarkLength" within "gridlines"

You can see the code for the solution below:

```
xAxes: [
    {
        id: 'first-x-axis',
        ticks: {
            display: false,
            min: <?php echo $min ?>, // Controls where axis starts
            max: <?php echo $max ?>, // Controls where axis finishes
            stepSize: <?php echo $step ?> // Control the gap between the first x-axis value and the last x-axis value
        },
        gridLines: {
            display: false,
            lineWidth: 7,
            tickMarkLength: 30// Adjusts the height for the tick marks area
        }
    }
]
```

I hope this helps!